# Get system language and use with ResourceBundle

Tags: java, localization, locale, resourcebundle

How would I get the system's current language and use that for the ResourceBundle?

Lets say the client's machine is running in Japanese, then I want my application to switch to Japanese, if that language file is not available, it should have a fallback solution.

I know I can use the ResourceBundle, but how would I accomplish the above mentioned setting?

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang", new Locale("jp", "JP"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource bundle automatically tries the system's current language, and then falls back to the default if that doesn't exist (`ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang")` will search in the following order, presuming that the system language is `jp_JP`: `lang_jp_JP.properties` -> `land_jp.properties` -> `lang.properties` ). You can look at the process ResourceBundle uses to resolve names [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

Comment: I still don't quite get how to set the default though. So If I have `ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang");` and it can't find the system language, how do I set the default then?

Comment: The default has no identifiers, it's just the normal lang.properties.

Answer (score 0):

From http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/

> For each language translation of  your product, you create a new
>   version of your initial resource bundle. For example, if you create
>   MyResource to store all English text, you will create a similarly
>   named file to store the French text. Resource bundles use a naming
>   convention that distinguishes the potentially numerous versions of
>   essentially the same bundle. Each bundle name consists of a base name
>   and an optional locale identifier. Together, these two pieces uniquely
>   identify a bundle in a package.
>
> Using the above example, the French version of the resources should be
>   named MyResource_fr_FR. The Canadian French version should be
>   MyResource_fr_CA.
>
> Appending the locale name to the base name of the bundle effectively
>   links the bundle's usage to a specific locale. **When you ask for the
>   bundle using ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyResource"), the getBundle
>   method appends the default locale identifier to the base name and
>   loads the appropriate bundle.** If the locale is fr_CA, then a call to
>   ResourceBundle.getBundle("MyResource") will load the MyResource_fr_CA
>   bundle.